# Updating columns with finite time to live (TTL)

Tags: cassandra

I am wondering if I can update a column with some finite TTL to be permanent, without any modification on its key or value. Should I remove this column first and recreate it afterwards? Or maybe updating it would be sufficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to re-insert the column without a TTL.  No need to remove it first.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - there's no way to modify only the TTL. You have to reinsert the column name and column value again as well, right? I would like to be able to say "whatever's in this row/column - modify the TTL"

Comment: Correct, there is no way to just modify the TTL.  The data is stored as a "(column name, column value, column timestamp, column ttl)" tuple inside Cassandra.  There is no way to "modify" just one part of a stored tuple.  You have to re-insert the whole thing.