# Can the TTL of tupule be updated without updating the tupule itself in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I am sort of noob to cassandra. I was wondering if it is possible to add expiry to a tupule without actually updating the tupule. I have not specified the TTL during INSERT of the tupule. Now I just want to update the TTL.

Is this possible?

Regards
Rajesh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating columns with finite time to live (TTL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507886/updating-columns-with-finite-time-to-live-ttl)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell there's no way to set only the `ttl`. You could probably re-set one of the values to allow you to pass in the `ttl`:

`UPDATE TABLE USING TTL 10 SET a_col = a_col WHERE key = key;`

See the syntax: [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#updateStmt)

*Note*: keep in mind that this will set the `TTL` for the `a_col` column and will result in an write operation.

*Update*: this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6511307/485496) is also a valid option.